# How to call C function printf for an integer from assembly code

Tags: c, linux, assembly, printf, 64-bit

I am having trouble calling printf from assembly code.  My function end_power is meant to print the result from power but whenever I call printf I get a segmentation fault. (I am running the program on linux in 64-bit) The only portion not working is the end_power function, more specifically the lines involved in the call to printf

```
# PURPOSE: This function is used to compute
#       the value of a number raised to
#       a power.
#
# INPUT:   First argument - the base number
#       Second argument - the power to
#       raise it to
#
# OUTPUT:  Will give the result as a return value
#
# NOTES:   The power must be 1 or greater
#
# VARIABLES:
#
#       %rbx - holds the base number
#       %rcx - holds the power
#
#       -8(%rbp) - holds the current result
#
#       %rax is used for temporary storage
#

.type power, @function
power:

    pushq   %rbp              # save old base pointer
    movq    %rsp, %rbp        # make stack pointer the base pointer
    subq    $8, %rsp          # get room for our local storage

    movq    16(%rbp), %rbx    # put first argument in %rax
    movq    24(%rbp), %rcx    # put second argument in %rcx

    movq    %rbx, -8(%rbp)    # store current result

power_loop_start:

    cmpq    $1, %rcx          # if the power is 1, we are done
    je      end_power

    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax    # move the current result into %rax
    imulq   %rbx, %rax        # multiply the current result by
                          # the base number
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)    # store the current result
    decq    %rcx              # decrease the power
    jmp     power_loop_start    # run for the next power

end_power:

    movq    -8(%rbp), %rdi    # return value goes in %rdi

    pushq -8(%rbp)
    pushq $fmtdec
    call printf
    add $16, %rsp

    movq    %rbp, %rsp        # restore the stack pointer
    popq    %rbp              # restore the base pointer
    ret
```

Comment: Are you trying to perform `printf(i)` or `printf("%d", i)`?

Comment: Have you tried writing the equivalent in C then looking at what the compiler assembles? (i.e. `gcc -S`)

Comment: The calling conventions are totally different. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#List_of_x86_calling_conventions First argument (format string pointer) in `%rdi`, next one in `%rsi`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calling convention for 64-bit-Linux are substantially different from the calling convention for 32-bit-Linux. Take a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI

Change

```
pushq -8(%rbp)
pushq $fmtdec
call printf
add $16, %rsp
```

to

```
mov $fmtdec,%rdi
mov -8(%rbp),%rsi
xor %eax, %eax
call printf
```

and consider that this overwrites your former "return value" in RDI.

Comment: Thanks that printed the two numbers being added together but not re result. I tried moving it into the main function after power returns but have not yet managed to change it to function there.  But thank you for pointing me in the right direction.